# Java: Abstract generic data context class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, datacontext

I would like to store all application data in a data context class.

Having application data classes `A` and `B` implementing `IApplicationData`, the non-abstract, non-generic version could look like this:

**NonGenericDataContext**

```
private List<A> aList;
private List<B> bList;

public List<A>getAs() {
    return aList;
}

public List<B>getBs() {
    return bList;
}
```

Now I would like to abstract from the concrete application classes and use a generic data context to use common functionality in multiple applications. The data context class could then look like this:

**AbstractGenericDataContext**

```
protected Map<Class<? extends IApplicationData>, List<? extends IApplicationData>> listsByType;

public List<? extends IApplicationData> getListByType(Class<? extends IApplicationData> clazz) {
    return objectListsByType.get(clazz);
}
```

I would love to use proper generics, but Java erases the type during compilation, hence the construct with `Class`. Unfortunately, the construct above makes the code cumbersome and return values of `getListByType()` need to be casted.

**Question** How could the code be improved to achieve an abstract, generic (not necessarily in a JLS sense, but with similar usability) data context class?

I would like stick with a pure Java solution (so no code generators if possible). Reflection would be ok if it does not slow down data access in a critical way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parameterize your generic function (the class doesnt't have to be abstract for that):

```
public class GenericContext {

    protected Map<Class<? extends IApplicationData>, List<? extends IApplicationData>> listsByType = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends IApplicationData> List<T> getListByType(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (List<T>) listsByType.get(clazz);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericContext context = new GenericContext();

        context.listsByType.put(ApplicationData.class, Arrays.asList(new ApplicationData()));
        context.listsByType.put(ApplicationData2.class, Arrays.asList(new ApplicationData2()));

        List<ApplicationData> list = context.getListByType(ApplicationData.class);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[ApplicationData@5ca881b5]
```